# R Markdown editor for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, markdown, r

Do you know of any plugin/editor that will display/handle [R Markdown](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/using_markdown) files (extension `.Rmd`) in Eclipse in a similar way as RStudio does (syntax highliting, ability to execute R code directly in the doc etc.)?

Seems like the developers of [StatET](http://www.walware.de/goto/statet) still don't support R Markdown.

Answer (score 1):

Statet http://www.walware.de/goto/statet does indicate a support of R Markdown documents from version 3.5.1. I tried and it works. You need to configure statet for knitr, in the external tool configurations, select `Run commands in active R console` and paste

```
require(knitr)
knit(input= "${resource_loc:${source_file_path}}")'
```

When you run the command, the document will be converted from rmd to a markdown (md) document. If you download the latest markdown text editor for eclipse you can then generate various format using right click>Wikitext>generate html